# spring boot - displaying object data from controller in JSP

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

I have a User class, two JSP and one controller. I want to register a user, store their details in a database (H2) and display user's name after registration.

This is my `home.jsp` -

```
<form action="addUser">
    <label>Name: </label><input type="text" name="name"/>
    <label>Id: </label><input type="number" name="id"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

This is my controller -

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    UserRepo usrrepoobj;
    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home()
    {
        return "home.jsp";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("addUser")
    public ModelAndView addUser(@RequestParam int id, User usr)
    {
        usrrepoobj.save(usr);
        User obj = usrrepoobj.findById(id).orElse(null);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.addObject(obj);
        mv.setViewName("afterRegister.jsp");
        
        //EVEN THIS DOESNT WORK
//      usrrepoobj.save(usr);
//      User obj = usr;
//      ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
//      mv.addObject(obj);
//      mv.setViewName("afterRegister.jsp");
        //EVEN THIS DOESNT WORK
        
        return mv;
    }
    
}
```

This is my `afterRegister.jsp` -

```
Registered as ${obj.name}
```

The object gets added to the database. What am I doing wrong when it comes to displaying the data in the next JSP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the below change in controller:

```
usrrepoobj.save(usr);
        User obj = usrrepoobj.findById(id).orElse(null);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.addObject("object",obj); //change this
        mv.setViewName("afterRegister.jsp");
```

In afterRegister.jsp -

```
Registered as ${object.name}
```

Answer (score 1):

Propably you don't know the ID of added user, thats why your `findById` return always `null`. Just return user from `save()` method. Show your entity of user.

```
@RequestMapping("addUser")
public String addUser(@RequestParam int id, User usr, Model model)
{
    User obj = usrrepoobj.save(usr);
    model.addAttribute("obj", obj);
    
    return "afterRegister.jsp";
}
```